# Select Row in primefaces data table

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I have this table:

[image]

```
<h:form>
    <p:dataTable id="books" value="#{ordersBean.userOrders}" var="book" selection="#{ordersBean.selectedBook}">
        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Order ID</f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{book[0]}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Title</f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{book[1]}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header"></f:facet>
            <p:commandButton id="selectRowBtn" value="select" action="#{ordersBean.showSelectedBook}"/>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

I want when i click on each `select` button, it's row information assigned to `selectedBook` property and displays it in `showSelectedBook()` method:

Here is the `ordersBean`:

```
private Book selectedBook = new Book();

public Book getSelectedBook() {
    return selectedBook;
}

public void setSelectedBook(Book selectedBook) {
    this.selectedBook = selectedBook;
}

public void showSelectedBook() {
    System.out.println("In selected Book(), book: " + getSelectedBook());
}
```

But result is this:

`In selected Book(), book: null`

Comment: Rows cannot be selected this way. You need to set `selectionMode` appropriately using one of two values `single` or `multiple`. Have a look at the [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml).

Comment: @Tiny But i don't need to show the selected rows in a dialog, i need to get the row in backing bean.

Comment: The dialog on the showcase examples is merely a demonstration. Row(s) shown on the dialog are coming from the associated managed which are selected in the respective data table - `<ui:repeat value="#{dtSelectionView.selectedCars}" var="car">` in case of multiple rows selection and `#{dtSelectionView.selectedCar}` in case of a single row selection. That dialog can simply be ignored, if not needed at all.

Comment: The linked showcase shows multiple ways to get the row in the backing bean. The 3rd example, eventsDT, is probably the most straightforward one.

Comment: get bookId in actionListener on click of button, iterate  bookList and extract Book object on successful match, assign it to selectedBook. Simple it is!!!

Comment: @ParkashKumar: Please explain **how** and if it is an actual answer, make it an answer.

Comment: What is the list of book? Does it contain Book object or raw Object?

Comment: This can also be done among other ways round - using a parameterized action(Listener) method, for example - you can just pass an instance of `Book` to a parameterized method (`public void showSelectedBook(Book book){...}`) such as `action="#{ordersBean.showSelectedBook(book)}"` given that you use EL 2.2 or higher  but it is then somewhat different from a row selection on a UI component. I basically avoid a parameterized method in such cases whenever the same can be done in a different way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show the selected book you have to set `selectionMode="single"` and there's no need to put a `commandButton` in each row, just specify only one `commandButton` in the footer facet like this:

```
<f:facet name="footer">
        <p:commandButton id="selectRowBtn" value="select" action="#{ordersBean.showSelectedBook}"/>
    </f:facet>
```

And your **main problem** here is that you are setting a `new Book()` to your `selectedBook` variable, so a `null` value to your `selectedBook` , this declaration:

```
private Book selectedBook = new Book();
```

Should be :

```
private Book selectedBook;
```

You don't have to instantiate a `new Book()` in your `selectedBook`.

Take a look at the second Example in this [**Showcase**](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml), to see how it works.

Answer (score 2):

Should be something like this:

XML code:

```
<p:commandButton id="selectRowBtn" value="select" 
    action="#{ordersBean.showSelectedBook}">
    <f:param name="bookId" value="#{book[0]}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

Java bean method:

```
public void showSelectedBook() {

    Map<String,String> params = 
        FacesContext.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();

    int bookId = Integer.valueOf(params.get("bookId"));

    for(Book book : bookList){
        if(book.bookId == bookId){
            selectedBook = book;
            break;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("In selected Book(), book: " + getSelectedBook());
}
```

Beside, you must have knowledge about the patterns for sending parameters to the actions, refer below link.
http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/4-ways-to-pass-parameter-from-jsf-page-to-backing-bean/

Answer (score 1):

better solution and without select button :

Xml code:

```
<p:dataTable id="ListBook"
    value="#{ordersBean.bookList}"
    selection="#{ordersBean.selectedBook}" var="book"
    rowKey="#{book.id}" selectionMode="single">

    <p:ajax event="rowSelect"
        listener="#{ordersBean.onRowSelectDataTable()}"
                                    update="ListBook" />
  ..... <columns> ..
</p:datatable>
```

Java bean:

```
private Book selectedBook=new Book();
private boolean headerButtonsDisabled=true;
//add a List object for all books (bookList) with getter and setter


public boolean isHeaderButtonsDisabled() {
        return headerButtonsDisabled;
    }

public void setHeaderButtonsDisabled(boolean headerButtonsDisabled) {
    this.headerButtonsDisabled = headerButtonsDisabled;
}

public void onRowSelectDataTable() {
    this.setHeaderButtonsDisabled(false);
}

public Book getSelectedBook() {
        return selectedBook;
    }

public void setSelectedBook(Book selectedBook) {
    this.selectedBook = selectedBook;
}
```